# character on 16X2 LCD is not visible properly

Tags: arduino-nano, lcd

i am using 16x2 LCD with arduino nano for my project.

when i connect arduino nano with usb power supply from pc or any mobile changer adapter then all the character on LCD is visible properly. But when i connect it with 5V regulated power to arduino nano than character on LCD is not visible properly (characters are visible and project is running fine but pixel which needs to be hidden are also little darker so it characters aren’t visible properly)

i have connected Vee pin of LCD with ground for maximum brightness.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnect Vee from GND and wire it up properly with a potentiometer. It doesn't set the brightness - it sets the bias point for displaying the different pixels in the matrix.

Comment: then how it is working fine when i connect USB as power supply.

Comment: Different voltages.